# How to prevent Google Chrome from remembering temporary session cookies

Tags: security, google-chrome, web-applications, session-cookies

### Question 1

My secure web application sets a session cookie for authenticated users which is not cleared even after I close my Chrome browser.

As a result, when a user tries to hit the dashboard page of my application after re-launching the browser (even restarting machine!), they are not asked to login again. Chrome is **NOT** set to "continue where I left off" which is also my next question.

I tested my bank's site under the same settings and it seems to force log out the user even when Network tab shows that same cookies are being retained (and sent with initial request header) for bank site as well. My server is Apache over SSL.

Can someone please point to some resource where I can handle this scenario because Chrome clearly is not clearing session cookie at the time of browser closing.

### Question 2

Now with the setting "continue where I left off" where it basically persists your sessional cookies and practically you can remain authenticated forever, is there a way to override/work around this Chrome feature.

When I see even my supposedly secure bank site letting a browser bypass security like that, it kind of makes me unnerved. Any suggestions there?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What ended up fixing this issue for me was to uncheck the:

***Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed***

setting under the *SYSTEM* section.

Hope this helps save some headaches....